# Finding the self-intersection of a cruve

Tags: curves

I need to find the self-intersection of the curve

[$$
C_1:x=t^2-5t+4, y=4\sin({\pi t\over 2}), 0 \le t \le 6
$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x=t%5E2-5t%2b4%20and%20y=4%2asin%28%28pi%2at%29/2%29%20with%200%20%3C=%20t%20%3C=%206)

I figured I would try to solve these equations on my TI-nspire:

$$t_1^2-5t_1+4=t_2^2+5t_2+4$$

$$4\sin({\pi t_1 \over 2})=4\sin({\pi t_2 \over 2})$$

for $t_1$ and $t_2$, but it gives me $t_1=-{(4n-13) \over 2}$ and $t_2={4n-3 \over 2}$ and I'm not sure how to proceed from here? why do I see an $n$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From intersection on the $x$ coordinate (you have a typo in your work)
$${\it t_1}^2-5\,{\it t_1}+4={\it t_2}^2-5\,{\it t_2}+4$$
gives
$$(t_1-t_2)(t_1+t_2-5)$$

So we want $$t_1 = 5-t_2$$

From the $y$ coordinates we want
$$\sin \left({{\pi\,{t_1}}\over{2}}\right)=\sin \left({{\pi\,
 { t_2}}\over{2}}\right)$$
So either
$$
{{\pi\,{t_1}}\over{2}} + {{\pi\,{t_2}}\over{2}} = \pi ~~ or \\
{{\pi\,{t_1}}\over{2}} =2 \pi - {{\pi\,{t_2}}\over{2}}
$$
First is not possible since $t_1+t_2=5$. Hence only the second holds. So we have
$$
t_1 = 4 + t_2, ~~~\text{and} ~~~t_1 + t_2 = 5$$
which gives
$$ { t_1}={{9}\over{2}} , { t_2}={{1}\over{2}} $$
and the point of intersection is
$$\left( {{7}\over{4}} , {{4}\over{\sqrt{2}}} \right) $$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have just added the picture of the curve,